# FileDoesNotExistException: File "basic.cfg" does not exist. Error observed when loading VizDoom

Tags: python, reinforcement-learning

I am facing this issue.

```
---------------------------------------------------------------------------
FileDoesNotExistException                 Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-15-5444ef3a9af5> in <module>
----> 1 game,possible_actions = create_environment()

<ipython-input-14-1cd1465efe04> in create_environment()
      3     #game.load_config("basic.cfg")
      4     #/usr/local/lib/python3.6/dist-packages/vizdoom/scenarios
----> 5     game.load_config("../../scenarios/basic.cfg")
      6     game.set_doom_scenario_path("basic.wad")
      7     game.init()

FileDoesNotExistException: File "../../scenarios/basic.cfg" does not exist.
```

My VizDoom installation is here:
/usr/local/lib/python3.6/dist-packages/vizdoom/scenarios/basic.cfg

I tried the below combinations:

```
game.load_config("../../scenarios/basic.cfg")

game.load_config("basic.cfg")

game.load_config("/usr/local/lib/python3.6/dist-packages/vizdoom/scenarios/basic.cfg")
```

But, nothing has worked so far. I am running the code on Jupyter notebook, file location: ~/Documents/TestProject/[filename.ipynb]
I am new to python and DeepQLearning, am i missing something?

Comment: That you can't open the file even with an absolute path seems strange. Try accessing the file with just a regular Python `open()` call, just to see if you can. That would clarify whether the problem is a `VisDoom` issue or just an issue with having the wrong path.

Answer (score 0):

If your `basic.cfg` is in `/usr/local/lib/python3.6/dist-packages/vizdoom/scenarios/basic.cfg`, then your code must be in `/usr/local/lib/python3.6/dist-packages/vizdoom/scenarios/folder1/folder2/your_code.py` for the line `game.load_config("../../scenarios/basic.cfg")` to work. Which I suspect is not where you want it to be. Please copy that file to the correct location.

Moreover, it seems that you are not using a virtual environment like conda or python3's `venv` package, which is not a good practice.

Comment: I set up a virtual environment using conda, as you suggested. Now, the code works with the absolute path: `game.load_config("/usr/local/lib/python3.6/dist-packages/vizdoom/scenarios/basic.cfg")` Btw, what part of my question gave you the impression that i was working without a virtual environment.....asking you coz that was the actual mistake i was making.

Comment: `/usr/local/lib/python3.6/dist-packages`, you were (and still) using the package installed in `/usr/local/lib`, which is not the path of virtual environment

Comment: Rectified.Now accessing using path: `/home/[username]/anaconda3/envs/py3.7/lib/python3.7/site-packages/vizdoom/scenarios/basic.cfg` Thanks for pointing out and correcting me.

Comment: OK, now think of this scenario. You need to collaborate and share this file with your team member, you probably do not want to send them `basic.cfg` separately, or upload your `site-packages` folder to git. What would you do?

Comment: I guess, the path should be relative instead of the absolute path I have used in my code. If I understand your question, that is what you want to imply. However, when I tried running my code with the absolute path `game.load_config("basic.cfg")`, my code would throw the "FileDoesNotExistException". Please guide.

Comment: Your path should be the same for every developer, but you are using `/home/[username]/`, which requires every developer to modify that part. I would place the config file in the directory inside the code repository. Relative path or absolute path should NOT matter if the file is there. When you run `python your_code.py`, the relative path should be to the path that you run the command. Hope it helps